# php _POST query parameter fails, but hard coded text query succeeds

Tags: php, mysql, post

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";
$database = "mydatabase";


$mypassword = "mypassword";

$receivedPassword = $_POST["pwd"];
if ($receivedPassword != $mypassword) {
    print "cedential failure";
} else {
    $unfiltered = $_POST["query"];
    //  print("unfiltered $unfiltered");

    $myquery = htmlspecialchars($unfiltered);
// Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    // print("filtered: $myquery");
// Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {

        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } else {
        print("conn ssuccessfull");
    }
    print('performing query: ' . $myquery);
    //$quer = (string)$myquery;
    $res = $conn->query($myquery); // or die(mysql_error());
    $enc = mb_detect_encoding($myquery);
    print("<br> encoding is: $enc <br>");
    $rows = array();
    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
        print($r);
    }
    print("ehere");
    print json_encode($rows);
    $conn->close();
}


?>
```

Here's an example of something I get printed back to me.

> conn successfull 
>   performing query: SELECT * FROM music_log2 WHERE (central_time > '2016-02-03 2:00:00' AND central_time < '2016-02-03 4:00:00') 
>   encoding is: ASCII 
>   ehere[]

Looking at the server log, I see:

> 2/27/2016 4:41:26 AM - www: PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /path/to/my/file.php on line 43

Note that in my sample output, I don't get a result. In fact the server log indicates that $res is false after:

```
res = $conn->query($myquery); // or die(mysql_error());
```

I've tried the die option, as you can see commented out, but I get no error output, just no more prints.

When I put the exact query hard coded by changing the query line to:

```
$res = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM music_log2 WHERE (central_time > '2016-02-03 2:00:00' AND central_time < '2016-02-03 4:00:00')");
```

It works FINE. 
Here is some output from changing the above line:

> conn successfull
>  performing query: SELECT * FROM music_log2 WHERE (central_time > '2016-02-03 2:00:00' AND central_time < '2016-02-03 4:00:00')
>  encoding is: ASCII
>  
>   ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray[{"field_number":"6","value":"Everything
>   Other Than Rotation","central_time":"2016-02-03
>   03:59:15","user_agent":"API","id":"1084793"},{"field_number":"2","value":"Title
>   Fight","central_time":"2016-02-03
>   03:59:15","user_agent":"API","id":"1084794"},{"field_number":"3","value":"Hyperview","central_time":"2016-02-03
>   03:59:15","user_agent":"API","id":"1084795"},{"field_number":"4","value":"Chlorine","central_time":"2016-02-03
>   03:59:15","user_agent":"API","id":"1084796"},
>   
> ...

Help. I'm super stumped. Been working on this for 2 days now.

I've also tried wrapping the query in double quotes:

```
$res = $conn->query('"' . $myquery . '"');
```

Same empty result.

Comment: Use `mysqli_real_escape_string` replacing `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: No function will provide you with any sort of protection from SQL injections if the entire query is provided by user input.

Comment: @A.B. what would be the reasoning for this in the context of this question?  Escape string functions would not work here, he's not escaping a single value, it would be on the entire query.

Comment: What  do you mean with $rows[] = $r; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the htmlspecialchars converts < to `&lt;` and > to `&gt;` which won't fly in you MySQL queries.

Comment: You are the kindest evil genius, and I am nothing but a fool.

Answer (score 0):

I am not to sure what your question is but i can still help in this way.

In your PHP script use the ".mysqli_connect_error()" method to see what is exatly giving you the error. Use it like this:

```
  if(!$connection){
    echo "Connectionn Error...".mysqli_connect_error();
}else{
    echo"Database connection Success...";
}
```

Call the PP script in your browser and you should echo back an error!